# Search Google or Search in Google

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

My first quest on English stack exchange, so please pardon me for the mistakes.

I have developed a search tool for which tagline is "Search smarter! Search Tool_Name.

But few people have objected that this sentence is not right. It should be:

"Search smarter! Search with (or in) Tool_Name.

Can you please help me explain if my tag line is grammatically correct?

Comment: The critics are grammatically (if dully) correct but if this is supposed to be a punchy attention-grabbing slogan it need not be grammatically correct. “Beanz meanz Heinz” is a good example of a non-grammatical but effective slogan. So why not use your “Search Smarter - Search Snooper!”

Comment: *Search Google!* could be parsed as an "adverbial" usage (*search **with / using** Google*, modifying the verb to specify ***how*** the act of searching is to be performed), rather than the direct object of a "transitive" usage (***Google*** being the thing / location searched). But "grammatically correct" isn't necessarily a relevant factor in context like this.

Comment: ... So 'Search Googler' would mean 'Use Google more often'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Or would that be *Search **Googlier**?*

Comment: That feels more like a (comparative) manner flat-adverb.

Comment: Search me. Grammatically correct, if not what you mean. But it’s a slogan, not a PhD thesis.